# How to run a background task in a j2ee application in JBoss?

Tags: multithreading, servlets, jakarta-ee, background-process, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using ServletContextListener to start the back end process. The problem with this approach is I can't control the web app as it is a listener. Other web apps can be controlled by enabling, disabling the application.

I am deploying the application through the JBOSS management console (localhost:9990) but application never get deployed. But the application is running.

Comment: Have you checked via Mbeans/JMX console?

Comment: Have you tried a `@Startup` and `@Singleton` EJB?

Comment: Thank you very much for both of you. I followed this example :  http://javatechig.com/java/servlets/running-infinite-timertask-in-java-servlet  . I removed the timer task and from the contextInitialized method called Mymain.main().   Mymain was the windows service (deamon) ran on the machine. Didn't do anything like you two mentioned.